# customize 403 error page depening on route in symfony 2.0

Tags: symfony, twig, http-status-code-403

i want to customize the error pages in Symfony 2.0

I know that this is done via overwriting the layouts in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/*` but I want to have different error pages for different routes.

I want one for backend and one for frontend.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you'll need to do is not too difficult.  Symfony allows you to explicitly specify which controller handles your exceptions.  So, in your config.yml, you can specify the exception controller under your twig configuration:

since Symfony 2.2

```
twig:
   exception_controller:  my.twig.controller.exception:showAction

services:
    my.twig.controller.exception:
        class: AcmeDemoBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
        arguments: [@twig, %kernel.debug%]
```

up to Symfony 2.1:

```
twig:
  exception_controller: AcmeDemoBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction
```

Then you can create a custom showAction that displays a custom error page based on a route:

```
<?php
namespace AcmeDemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as BaseExceptionController;

class ExceptionController extends BaseExceptionController
{
    public function showAction(FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $format = 'html')
    {
        if ($this->container->get('request')->get('_route') == "abcRoute") {
            $appTemplate = "backend";
        } else { 
            $appTemplate = "frontend";
        }

        $template = $this->container->get('kernel')->isDebug() ? 'exception' : 'error';
        $code = $exception->getStatusCode();

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
            'AcmeDemoBundle:Exception:' . $appTemplate . '_' . $template . '.html.twig',
            array(
                'status_code'    => $code,
                'status_text'    => Response::$statusTexts[$code],
                'exception'      => $exception,
                'logger'         => null,
                'currentContent' => '',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Obviously you should probably customize the if statement where it tests the current route to fit your needs, but this should do it.

You might want to add code that defaults to the normal Twig error pages if you don't have a specific error template created.  For more information, check out the code in

```
Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
```

as well as

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. Works like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

i use 
`arguments: ["@twig", "%kernel.debug%"]`
 instead of 
`arguments: [@twig, %kernel.debug%]`