# Symfony2 - Modifying Exception Controller

Tags: symfony

I am trying to create custom exception pages in Symfony 2, and am following the Symfony 2 guide [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller). The second link says to modify the controller found `Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\Controller\\ExceptionController::showAction`, but I can only find that file in the `vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller` folder. From my understanding, I should never modify anything in the `vendors` folder.

I am wondering where is the `ExceptionController` I should be modifying located?

Comment: You don't want to modify any vendor files. You want to create a new ExceptionController.

I answered a similar question on how to modify ExceptionControllers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282690/customize-403-error-page-depening-on-route-in-symfony-2-0/14286165

Comment: @Mike So do I ignore the ExceptionController inside the Vendor directory?

Comment: Can you give me more details on what you want to accomplish? Do you simply need to modify the HTML/twig templates?  Is there custom PHP code you need to execute before displaying the exception templates?

Comment: @Mike I need to modify a twig/html template to display a 404 and 500 error page. There should not be any custom PHP code that needs to be executed prior to displaying the exception page.

Comment: For the `config.yml`, I am wondering if you are talking about the `services.yml` inside the `config` folder?

Comment: I'm referring to wherever you keep your twig configuration in your app/config directory (the default is in config.yml).

Comment: @Mike Perfect, I found the config.yml. I was looking in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to override the symfony error templates, take the templates from

```
vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception
```

and place the ones you want to customize in a app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception directory.  Then customize as needed.

If you want to render templates based on the application, see my answer @ [customize 403 error page depening on route in symfony 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282690/customize-403-error-page-depening-on-route-in-symfony-2-0/14286165)

Comment: Would I be putting my error pages in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception`?

Comment: I also don't understand the `if` statement in your code. Does the `if` mean if they enter in that route, redirect them to a backend template? Sorry, I am new to PHP and frameworks.

Comment: Based on what? Implementing the solution in the other post?  If you're using the solution in the other post, you can put them anywhere.  The `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` would primarily be if you only want to customize the error templates, and not override the exception controller.

Comment: @Jon -- If you are new to PHP, Symfony2 is going to be a tough thing to comprehend.  I suggest reading the documentation from top to bottom to get a clear understanding of what's going on.  Error templates are going to be the least of your issues. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained myself better. I would like to override the exception controller as I am using your solution from your other post. I am currently learning PHP/Symfony on my own time, but at the same time I need to help my team on the project.

Comment: You can ignore that if statement most likely.. Just remove it.  That if statement is basically saying if the user is on a certain page, load a "backend_*" template, otherwise load "frontend_*" template.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you. I'll try implementing your solution. Hopefully all goes well :)

Comment: Good luck in your journey! (Symfony2 is like golf -- lifetime to master!)

Comment: Hopefully I will be able to get get at least a bogey within the week. I'm still confused about where/how to point the controller to my error pages which are located at `AcmeDemoBundle/Reousrces/views/Pages/Errors/404.html.twig`. I am looking at the `return` statement you wrote in your `ExceptionController` and I am unsure how that return statement would find my template. In the `ExceptionController` in the `/vendors` directory, I understand that it would look in a directory and find a page that had the same name as the error code. Is that similarly what is happening in your `return` statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to change the layout of the error pages, creating the files on `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` should be enough.

But if you need to pass additional parameters to your error pages you should override the default `ExceptionController`.
To do that, you should create a new controller that extends the default one:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
class MyExceptionController extends ExceptionController {
    //override the showAction() or findTemplate() method here
}
```

Then you need to tell symfony to use your new controller.
This can be done by adding a new parameter on your `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    twig.controller.exception.class: YourBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
```

Comment: Tried this but getting an exception:
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 404
[reason phrase] Not Found

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't

```
parameters:
twig.controller.exception.class: YourBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
```

but

```
parameters:
twig.controller.exception.class: YourNamespace\YourBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
```

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 4 you need this:

```
class TwigExceptionControllerCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('twig.controller.exception');
        $definition->setClass(TwigExceptionController::class);
    }
}
```