# Symfony2 - ExceptionController - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: symfony

I am trying to create a custom exception error page and I have been following [Mike's tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14286165/1277607). I have inserted the following code into config.yml, and created an ExceptionController in `StoreBundle\Controller\ExceptionController.php`. When I try to test my 404 error page by going `local.store.com/fake-page`, I get a `NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /fake-page"` error. I thought my ExceptionController is suppose to redirect all users if a page is not found so I added a `var_dump('testing')` in it but it never dumped. I tried to remove the code I injected into `config.yml` and I get the default Symfony error page instead. Am I doing something wrong in `config.yml`?

Inserted into `app/config/config.yml`:

```
twig:
    exception_controller: StoreBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction
```

**EDIT**

I now think my problem is in my controller. This is what I have in `StoreBundle\ControlleExceptionController.php`. My error pages are in `StoreBundle\Resources\views\Pages\Errors\404.html.twig` and `StoreBundle\Resources\views\Pages\Errors\500.html.twig`

```
<?php
namespace StoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as BaseExceptionController;

class ExceptionController extends BaseExceptionController
    {
        public function showAction(FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $format = 'html')
        {
            $template = $this->container->get('kernel')->isDebug() ? 'exception' : 'error';
            $code = $exception->getStatusCode();

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
            'StoreBundle:Exception:Pages/Errors:' . $code . '.html.twig', array(
                'status_code'    => $code,
                'status_text'    => Response::$statusTexts[$code],
                'exception'      => $exception,
                'logger'         => null,
                'currentContent' => '',
            ));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Squazic I don't think so. I modified my `app.php` to say `$kernel = new AppKernel('local', true);`

Comment: Error pages only work in prod mode unless you've specifically configured your environment otherwise.

Comment: @Squazic I went to `local.store.com/app.php/fake-page` (my understanding is app.php means prod` and received the same error of NotFoundHttpException. I am starting to think there is a problem with my controller. I am going to modify my question to include my controller code in a minute.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you want the second argument to [AppKernel](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.html) to be false if you want debug to be off, which thus enables error messages.

Comment: @Squazic I've modified my question. In the dev env, I am now getting a Chrome 500 error.