# Can't override the default Exception Controller in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to override the default exception controller. I tried to follow the official Symfony 2 cookbook and also [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282690/customize-403-error-page-depening-on-route-in-symfony-2-0/14286165).

Steps I did:

1. In my bundle (Ed) I created new controller file named `MyExceptionController.php` :

   ```
   <?php
   use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;

   class MyExceptionController extends ExceptionController 
   {

       //override the showAction() or findTemplate() method here
       public function showAction($token)
       {   
           if (null === $this->profiler) {
               throw new NotFoundHttpException('The profiler must be enabled.');
           }

           $this->profiler->disable();

           $exception = $this->profiler->loadProfile($token)->getCollector('exception')->getException();
           $template = $this->getTemplate();

           if (!$this->twig->getLoader()->exists($template)) {
               $handler = new ExceptionHandler();

               return new Response($handler->getContent($exception), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'));
           }

           $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
           $name = "Mark";
           return new Response($this->twig->render(
               $template,
               array(
                   'status_code'    => $code,
                   'status_text'    => Response::$statusTexts[$code],
                   'exception'      => $exception,
                   'logger'         => null,
                   'currentContent' => '',
                   'name' => $name,
               )
           ), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'));
       }
   }
   ```
2. In my `config.yml` file I placed:

   ```
   twig:
       debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
       strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
       autoescape: false
       exception_controller:  twig.controller.exception:showAction

   services:
       twig.controller.exception:
           class: EdProfileBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController
           arguments: [@twig, %kernel.debug%]
   ```

I also have a customized exception.html.twig page that worked fine before I overrode the Exception Controller. Now, when exception occurs I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'EdProfileBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController' not found in (..)\app\cache\prod\appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2951
```

Is something wrong in the names/location in `config.yml` (for instance: do I have to change `twig.controller.exception` to smth else?) or the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: try : `class: \EdProfileBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController`

Comment: I got the following error: \EdProfileBundle\\Controller\\MyExceptionController'" is not a valid class name for the "twig.controller.exception" service

Comment: You are missing your `namespace` in your `Controller` class. Add `namespace EdProfileBundle\Controller;` to the top of your file.

Comment: Ferdynator: thanks for suggestion, but I got the following error: Fatal error: Class 'EdProfileBundle\Controller\MyExceptionController' not found in (...)\app\cache\prod\appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2951

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `arguments: ["@twig", "%kernel.debug%"]` instead of `arguments: [@twig, %kernel.debug%]`